# Erase element from vector,and the vector is fill with struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, erase

something like this:

```
struct mystruct 
{
  char straddr[size];
  int port;
  int id;
  .......
};

mystruct s1={......};
mystruct s2={......};
mystruct s3={......};

vector test;
test.emplace_back(s1);
test.emplace_back(s2);
test.emplace_back(s3);
```

now i want to erase the element with straddr="abc" and port = 1001.
what should i do?
And i don't want to do it like this.

```
    for(auto it = test.begin();it != test.end();)
   {
      if(it->port == port && 0 == strcmp(it->straddr,straddr))
         it = test.erase(it);
     else
        it++;
   }
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment to me

Comment: @barq,@HairOfTheDog i tried to do it with for loop .But i think it's .....stupid.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, use `std::string` instead of `char [size]` so that you can use `==` instead of `strcmp` and other such c-string functions.

Then use `std::remove_if()` along with `erase()` as:

```
test.erase (
    std::remove_if(
        test.begin(), 
        test.end(), 
        [](mystruct const & s) { 
            return s.port == 1001 && s.straddr == "abc"; 
        }
    ), 
    test.end()
);
```

It is idiomatic solution to your problem and you can read more about it here:

- [C++ Idioms/Erase-Remove](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove)

Note that this solution will remove all elements from the container for which the predicated returns `true`. However, if it is known in advance that there will be at most one item matching the predicate, then `std::find_if` accompanied with `erase()` would be faster:

```
auto it = std::find_if(
             test.begin(), 
             test.end(), 
             [](mystruct const & s) { 
               return s.port == 1001 && s.straddr == "abc"; 
             }
          );
if(it != test.end())//make sure you dont pass end() iterator.
    test.erase(it);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: erase/remove_if is a good technique to share, but the question does say *"want to erase the element"* - if "the" wasn't carelessly used and there's known to be at most one match, a `find_if` and targeted `erase` would be faster.

Comment: @TonyD: I thought about the possibility of that interpretation as well, but then I saw the *for* loop in the question, so I suggested an equivalent solution.

Comment: Fair point, and with the C tag too - lots of scope for variation in answers... O_o.

Comment: @TonyD: Added the solution for other possible interpretation.